# HTML Redirect in specific section

Tags: html

How to redirect another page in HTML but in a specific section of that page? Images are provided below for clearer overview of the problem. I find it difficult to explain in detail but you will get it somehow and thanks in advance.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use anchor tag `#section` and href will redirect to the element with that id:

```
<a href="another_page.html#section">Performance and Grades</a>
```

In another_page.html

```
<div id="section">
   .......
</div>
```

Comment: i have done same but it only redirecting home of the specified section page , what am i missing here? is it due to js?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a lot of detail, so if you just want to scroll the page up on page load a JavaScript snippet would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("window.scrollBy(0,280);",10);
</script>
```

You can set the timer and scrolling parameters to whatever suits.   If that's not what you're after, we'll need to see some of your code.